# Dialogflow Webhook not working when calling from External Angular 6 Chat Window

Tags: angular, firebase, angular6, dialogflow-es

I have created a Dialogflow chatbot. In which I have created a webhook to integrate it with firebase. The chatbot and webhook are working fine when a user is asking questions to the bot from Internal dialogflow chat box(chat window).

I wanted to create my custom chat window. So I created one using Angular 6. Integrated my Angular front end with the dialogflow chat agent. For this Angular chat window dialogflow chatbot is working fine for static questions, but when I query for a intent that uses a webhook, I am getting below error in logs:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
>       at V2Agent.processRequest_ (/user_code/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/v2-agent.js:108:86)
>       at new WebhookClient (/user_code/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:201:17)
>       at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:14:17)
>       at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:26:47)
>       at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:714:7
>       at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:697:11
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)

Below is my **index.js** file (web fulfillment)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

// initialise DB connection
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
});

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug';

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function handleAge(agent) {
    const name = agent.parameters.Name;

    agent.add('Thank you... ' + name);

    return admin.database().ref('ageInfo').once("value").then((snapshot) => {
      var averageAge = snapshot.child(name).val().Age;
      agent.add(`Our recorded age is ` + averageAge);
    });
  }

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('AskAge', handleAge);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "~6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^4.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.5.7",
    "dialogflow": "^0.1.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "0.3.0-beta.3",
    "actions-on-google": "2.0.0-alpha.4"
  }
}
```

I went through so many articles on Github and StackOverFlow, but none is helpful.

Comment: Please do let me know if you need my Angular Project setup details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the resolution to above issue. I updated 2 properties in **package.json** file of dialogflow fulfillment (inline editor):

**Old Values :**

```
"dialogflow-fulfillment": "0.3.0-beta.3",

"actions-on-google": "2.0.0-alpha.4"
```

**New Values :**

```
"dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.4.1",

"actions-on-google": "^2.1.3"
```

Comment: So the issue was with the version of the packages not being up to date? Did you make more progress with this?

I am stuck with a similar issue with the dialogflow-fulfillment package, and it seems to be deprecated.

Comment: I am still working on same old version of dialogflow and working fine for me. I haven't updated since then. I will check with latest version and let you know.